# imap_open(): Couldn't open stream (imap ssl)

Tags: php, email, ssl, stream, imap

I'm trying to read emails from imap mail with the php library [ddeboer/imap](https://github.com/ddeboer/imap) .

I've created a subdomain like this: abm.mydomain.be . The IMAP extension wasn't installed so I asked the server administrator to install it. The function `imap_open` now exists. But now I'm getting the following error:

```
AuthenticationFailedException in Server.php line 76:
Authentication failed for user abm@mydomain.be with error imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {mail.mydomain.be:993/imap/ssl/validate-cert}
```

The user and passwords are correctly (100% sure of that). When I check phpinfo I see the following with imap:

[image]

Does anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Either the address is wrong, or requests are blocked on network level or the certificate is invalid or your credentials are wrong. We cannot say. You need to take a lok at the imap servers log file for more information.

Comment: have you manually checked whether there is a firewall?